# get initialValue and getFieldDecorator of Ant Design Form form a json data

Tags: reactjs, forms, antd

I am new to React and I am stuck here.

I have a JSON data and I want my Ant Design `Form` should get it's `initialValue` and `getFieldDecorator` from that JSON data. I know I should use a `map`, but not know how exactly I can do it.
In the give sandbox example, my form should have an initial value from `data` i.e. it should have `Test` as it's the initial value. Please help me to solve this.

Thank you.

Reference: https://codesandbox.io/s/antd-getfielddecorator-imseg?file=/index.js

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `initialValue` and init it with your data stucture e.g.

`initialValue: data.content.people.name[0].name,`